# Show two functions f: N -> N , g: N -> N such that f is injective, g is surjective and the composition gof isn't injective and surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show two functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ , $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective and the composition $g \circ f$ isn't injective and surjective.  I can't find $f$ and $g$ such that meet these requirements. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about letting $g$ be the identity?

Comment: I am intrigued by your chosen tag. Why abstract algebra, and not something else?

Answer (score 6):

Define $g(n) = \frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even, and $g(n) = 1$ otherwise. Then $g$ is surjective.

Define $f(n) = 2n + 1$, which is injective.

Then $g \circ f$ is a function which is identically $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really mean "isn't injective *and* surjective"?

For example, what if you have $f(n) = n^2$ and $g(n) = n$.

Then $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective, and the composition is just $f$, which is not both injective and surjective. (It is not surjective; for example, nothing maps to $2$.)